# Who are the top 10 players with most successful dribbles in a single World Cup?

Tags: football

There is a well known list of top 10 players with most successful dribbles in all world cups since 1966. To build this list, you need to know how many successful dribbles each player did in each single world cup. There is some articles around claiming Garrincha is #1 (ironically because he played in 1958 and 1962), but no other players are mentioned.

Who are the top 10 players with most successful dribbles in a single World Cup (at least since 1966)?

Comment: How _precisely_ are you defining "successful dribble"? It's clearly not something defined in the Laws of the Game.

Comment: @PhilipKendall the same way those who made the top 10 players with most successful dribbles in all world cups have defined it, whatever that definition is. As stated in the question, if those who created the top 10 players with most successful dribbles in all world cups made a definition and that statistic, a statistic with the same definition for most successful dribbles in a single world cup has to exist.

Comment: Are you asking us to find a list that already exists?

Comment: @F1Krazy No, I'm asking if anyone knows the datasource of both lists. Out of that data source, you can make both lists and give the answer

Comment: Can you post a link to the well known list? I couldn't find it, at least not immediately